# How to use JSON correctly with PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json, datatable

I am facing problem while reloading the page. There is no error in the console.
When I delete a JSON file from the directory and reload the page it works initially while show the below error when I reload the page again and again & so on.

NOTE: The JSON format is perfect, there is no issue in pattern.

> Error: DataTables warning: table id=myTable1 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

PHP Code

```
$file = "arrays.json";
$fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET["state"];
$json_array_source  =   json_decode(json_encode(array_chunk($data, 3, false)), false);

$json_array_target  =   array();
foreach ($json_array_source as $key => $value) {
$json_array_target["data"][]  =   $key + 1;
foreach ($value as $sub_key => $sub_value) {
$json_array_target[$sub_key][]  =   $sub_value;
}}

$json_array_target["data"] = $json_array_source;

$transformed_string = json_encode($json_array_target);
fwrite($fh, $transformed_string);
fclose($fh);
```

JavaScript Code

```
 ('table.table').DataTable({
 ajax: 'data.json',
 processing: true,
 serverSide: true,
 scrollY: 400,
 scrollCollapse: false,
 paging: true
});
```

Comment: Pls add you json data to check

Comment: Might be trivial, but in PHP you're creating a file arrays.json, but in JS you're requesting data.json. Open the network tab in Chrome Developers tool, (or any other browser) and make sure there's no 404 error and you're requesting an existing file. Also make sure that in PHP, you're creating the file in a public directory. Is the PHP script located itself in the public directory?